# Wrap xml node with <A> tag using C#.net

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am trying to wrap a href tags around all the image tags return from the webservice using C#.net.
I have the following code to get all the images

```
foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("Document/Content//img"))
{
    // After I get the img I need to wrap a <a> tag around the image with an onclick attribute
}
```

Can some one help me with the code? I am not able to add the xml returned from the webservice to this Question.

Comment: you didn't give enough information for someone to give you a proper answer - what does the XML look like? Do you want us to guess? Is there anything specific you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach (XmlElement el in xDoc.SelectNodes("//img")) {
    // Replace image element with an 'a' element that wraps it
    var aElement = xDoc.CreateElement("a");

    aElement.SetAttribute("href", "http://example.com");
    aElement.SetAttribute("onclick", "alert('Maple syrup!');");
    aElement.AppendChild(el.Clone());

    el.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(aElement, el);
}
```

Note that the type I've used in the loop is `XmlElement` instead of `XmlNode` (since all `img` elements should be... elements, and that allows us to do more stuff than just the base `XmlNode` class allows).

You may also want to look into [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx), which makes creating XML much less annoying :-)

Comment: Actually, does anyone else know of a better way to do this? My method feels a little clunky...